# How can I create a basic NASM Assembly (Linux) calculator to add two integers?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I had a go at it, and tried:

```
section .data
promptmsg: db 'Enter integer: '
msgsize: equ $-promptmsg

section .bss       ;creating variables to store input
firstnum: resb 6
secondnum: resb 6

section .text
global _start

_start:

xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx

mov eax, 4          ;system call to write
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, promptmsg
mov edx, msgsize
int 80h

xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx

mov eax, 3               ;system call to read
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, firstnum
mov edx, 6
int 80h

push firstnum

xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx

mov eax, 4              ;system call to write
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, promptmsg
mov edx, msgsize
int 80h

xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx

mov eax, 3                ;system call to read
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, secondnum
mov edx, 6
int 80h

push secondnum

xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx

pop eax
pop ebx
add eax, ebx         ;attempt to add firstnum and secondnum and store in EAX

push eax

xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx

mov eax, 4          ;once again a system call to write
mov ebx, 1
pop ecx
mov edx, 7
int 80h

xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx

mov eax, 1             ;exit safely and return 0
mov ebx, 0
int 80h
```

Sorry about all the XOR instructions, I just wanted to make sure registers were cleared before I used them for a system call, I'm still learning assembly and not sure about what instructions will render a register empty.

When I compile, link and run this I can enter the two integers only if I include the ENTER character, i.e. newline character. An integer can't be added to it, so already that causes a problem. So when I enter both of them, I get no further output on the screen from the program, and the it just ends.

How can I correct it?

(Using C or C++ with ASM is not an option in this case.)

Comment: "add eax, ebx ;attempt to add firstnum and secondnum and store in EAX" is actually adding the *addresses* of firstnum and secondnum. You have to convert the ascii data stored in the buffers before you can add them (this will also let you do validation and ignore the newline) and the convert that number to a ascii string buffer before printing it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about "correcting" your code as it is about writing a missing part of it.

You have to parse integers, ignoring separating whitespace. Add them, then convert a result into a string. Then output this string. Calling `scanf` or `strtol` or `printf` is probably inacceptable to you, as it's using a standard C library.